# My compare response function between user and computer does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a Simon game. I don't understand why the `compareResponse` function does not work when I finished clicking the button and the two arrays compared exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would expect a two arrays to be printed out to the console since I defined them as global variables but when I console.log them nothing came out.

Here is what I tried so far. I could upload my HTML code for better consultation

See the Pen [Simon Game](https://codepen.io/Lamdepzai123/pen/RQGVXM/) by Lam ([@Lamdepzai123](https://codepen.io/Lamdepzai123)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Perhaps logging `randomSequence.toString()` and `userSequence.toString()` might help you discover how they differ.

Comment: I tried console.log the two arrays but they don't appear in the console, my compareResponse function is not initiating...

Comment: If `compareResponse()` isn't firing, then it's fairly safe to assume that the call to it isn't happening.  It appears to be called only if `userSequence.length == randomSequence.length`.  This must be failing, you want to get your `console.log(randomSequence, userSequence)` above that.  Once you get the output I imagine it'll become clearer.

Comment: Yeah I tried but the function still does not firing... The two array appear to be similar

Comment: You'll want to provide the HTML, yes. And sample inputs and what output you're expecting that you're not seeing. See [mcve].

Comment: I expect the function to be executed while nothing is printed out to the console

Comment: I just modified my post with full code

Comment: Your `console.log`s should be inside the `compareResponse` function, not outside of it.

Comment: The issue is `compareResponse` is not working...